# Breakdown of butyl rubber

Tags: acid-base, redox

I'm in my high school's theatre crew and of course we build a lot of props and such. However I just opened (yesterday) an old drawer of screwdrivers and they smelled like puke! I know that the chemical responsible for that smell is butyric acid, so the rubber must have been a butyl rubber. Could someone point out the chemical equation that shows the reaction for this?

Comment: If ever, it would be rather isobutyric or isovaleric acid, as butyl rubber is copolymer of isobutene with few percents of isoprene.

Comment: One really does not know much until a chemical analysis is done.